# Tab Page Error: The requested method GET is not allowed

Tags: facebook

I have just set up a custom tab on my page for the first time. I have thoroughly followed the setup guide and seem to have everything on the Facebook side setup correctly.

However when I view [my page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/FeeB-Naturals/266917293340214?sk=app_162238667196141) it throws the following error:

> Method Not Allowed The requested method GET is not allowed for the
>   URL /Facebook/index.html. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was
>   encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the
>   request. Apache/1.3.41 Server at feebnaturals.com.au Port 80

I believe it may be some kind of Apache server config issue, however I'm not that Apache savvy, so not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but instead of GET, it was POST method which was not allowed. This is a setting on your server. Not server savvy myself, but it seems that my provider didn't allow this method on html-page, but makes no problem on doing the same for php-pages. So all I did was rename my page from .html to .php, updated the app settings in facebook and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an error on your side, check your server logs and see what they say - it looks like you've configured the page to only work via a POST request and it's being requested in a GET request